# Split area into equal size squares, count number of records for each segment

Tags: postgis, postgresql

I'm working on a project where I have a series of points, something like this:

```
| id   | name        | geom  |
|------|-------------|-------|
| 1    | example a   | point |
| 2    | example b   | point |
| .. 
| 641  | example bcc | point |
```

Given a bounding area (always rectangular), such as:

```
{
    "type": "Polygon",
    "coordinates": [
      [
        [
          -0.23895263671874997,
          51.390637019843744
        ],
        [
          0.06866455078125,
          51.390637019843744
        ],
        [
          0.06866455078125,
          51.59413527860747
        ],
        [
          -0.23895263671874997,
          51.59413527860747
        ],
        [
          -0.23895263671874997,
          51.390637019843744
        ]
      ]
    ]
  }
```

I wish to divide the area into 100 equal size segments, and calculate the total count of records for that area (the intention being when a user zooms in, the bounding box can be narrowed and more specific results provided).

For example, returning something like this:

```
| geom    | count |
|---------|-------|
| polygon | 26    |
| polygon | 12    |
| polygon | 8     |
```

I haven't been able to find any function for splitting a polygon other than by a Line, however this would require creating 18 lines (9 vertical, 9 horizontal), then looping over them. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here](https://gist.github.com/tomplex/6d44713b259d36f2aa3f1a1ac344eb8e) is a PostgreSQL / PostGIS function that will divide up a `box2d` object into equal-sized cells.

You can then use the created grid to get a count like so:

```
SELECT
  cell_id,
  count(*)
FROM my_points
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT
    (create_grid(st_extent(geom), 6, 20, 4326)).* -- fill out the proper SRID here
  FROM my_points
   ) grid
ON my_points.geom && grid.geom AND st_intersects(my_points.geom, grid.geom)
GROUP BY grid.geom, cell_id;
```

You've probably already figured something out by now, but I hope this helps.